# Is it possible to backup users from MongoDB admin database?

Tags: backup, mongodb, users

The title sums it up nicely. 
Essentially what I am asking is, if its possible to backup (use mongodump perhaps?) only users (accounts created for human users)?

Comment: It should be possible to backup just collection `admin.system.users`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit actually turns out you **cant**. Read my answer to the question for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after digging around further i found how to do that.

In short i needed to take the **system.users** collection or rather use a query to get only users from that collection that follow a certain pattern. for me it was user@some.domain, without the query i would have gotten all service users also which i did not want or need.

The tricky part was mongorestore which did not work if i wanted to restore only the **system.users** collection

The error i got was:

```
2020-01-28T12:44:49.902+0200    assuming users in the dump directory are from <= 2.4 (auth version 1)
2020-01-28T12:44:49.960+0200    Failed: the users and roles collections in the dump have an incompatible auth version with target server: cannot restore users of auth version 1 to a server of auth version 5
2020-01-28T12:44:49.960+0200    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

I got the error because mongorestore is unable to determine the version of the dump mongo if you dont give it **system.version** collection also.